# BackboneJs fetch() Json to display on View

Tags: json, backbone.js

I am trying to use backbonejs to fetch() JSON data that sent from server to display it in a view. But it doesn't work.

Here is my backbonejs

```
$(function () {


var Service = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/api/album/1",
    defaults: {
        id: '1',
        title: 'abc',
        article: 'abc'

    },
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }
});


// Create a collection of services
var ServiceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // Will hold objects of the Service model
    url: "/api/album/1",
    model: Service

});

var ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        'click': 'toggleService'
    },
    initialize: function () {

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    render: function () {

        this.$el.html('<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="' + this.model.get('title') + '" /> ' + this.model.get('title') + '<span>$' + this.model.get('artist') + '</span>');
        this.$('input').prop('checked', this.model.get('checked'));

        return this;
    },
    toggleService: function () {
        this.model.toggle();
    }
});

var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    model: Service,
    el: $('#main'),
    initialize: function () {
       this.model = new ServiceList();
        this.model.fetch();


        this.list = $('#services');

       this.model.each(function (service) {

            var view = new ServiceView({model: service});
            this.list.append(view.render().el);

        }, this);
    },
    render: function () {

        return this;

    }

});

new App();
});
```

Here is my JSON

> {"data":{"id":"1","artist":"Gotye","title":"Making  Mirrors"}}

Please ignore my bad naming convention in the backbonejs, i am  trying to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#main'),

  initialize: function() {
    var serviceList = new ServiceList(),
      // if you don't have #services in html
      //services    = $(this.el).html('<div id="services"></div>'),
      services = $(this.el).find('#services'),
      serviceView;

    serviceList.fetch({
      success: function(collection) {
        collection.each(function(model) {
          serviceView = new ServiceView({
            model: model
          });

          services.append(serviceView.render().el);
        });
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return this;
  }
});
```

DEMO: [http://jsbin.com/hiziqi/1/](http://jsbin.com/hiziqi/1/edit?js,output) in this demo I changed url to remote server